# IP masquerading, what if the router runs out of ports?

Tags: networking, ip, port

I have recently discovered ip masquerading.

My question is simple: if routers actually map hosts ports to their own ports, what if they run out of ports ? Suppose the network has got 4 hosts on IPs 192.168.0.{2,3,4,5}, each using 20000 ports, how does a router map 80000 ports to his 65000.

Although I couldn't find any information on this, I am guessing masquerading occurs on traffic only, thus there shouldn't be 20k ports to map per host, but why not ? I can't figure it out.

Comment: This seems like more of a Server/Network infrastructure related question.  It should probably be moved off SO, because it's off topic - SO is only for programming questions.

Comment: Donald W gave you the answer to your question, i would just add that if we are talking about consumer grade equipment, your router will be dead long before you reach the 80000 translations you mentioned :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by 'using 20000 ports'.  If you had an application which was listening on 20000 ports on each of 192.168.0.{2,3,4,5} (perhaps allocating the external mapping dynamically using UPnP, it *would* exhaust the available ports eventually.  It's possible that a quota would prevent anywhere near 65000 being allocated.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6887#section-17.2

However, you are probably talking about connections *out* from 192.168.0.{2,3,4,5} to the wider Internet.  In this case, no ~65000 limit would apply because a socket is a defined based on the {source ip, source port, dest ip and dest port}.  N.B. It's possible to open more than ~65000 sockets from a single server (assuming the OS is so configured), and therefore it's also possible, in theory, to do so with IP masquerading.

A more comprehensive answer is here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/541699/nat-gateway-maximum-connection-limit